# Can nextAll() skip any specified parent element and look for only child inside the parent?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

I have html ajax form structure like below:

```
<form name="vafForm" id="vafForm" method="GET" action="urlfor ajax">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="vafProduct">
            <!--<div id="catalog-collection" class="select">-->

        <select class="catSelect {prevLevelsIncluding: 'cat'} cat" name="cat" id="catalog" data-level="0">

            <option value="0">- Select Cat -</option>

                        <option value="1">
                Federal            </option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="2">
                California            </option>

        </select>

        <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div id="year-collection" class="select">-->

        <select class="yearSelect {prevLevelsIncluding: 'cat,year'} year" name="year" id="year" data-level="1"><option value="0">- Select Year -</option><option value="7">2016</option><option value="3">2012</option></select>

        <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div id="make-collection" class="select">-->

        <select class="makeSelect {prevLevelsIncluding: 'cat,year,make'} make" name="make" id="make" data-level="2"><option value="1">Acura</option></select>

        <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div id="model-collection" class="select">-->

        <select class="modelSelect {prevLevelsIncluding: 'cat,year,make,model'} model" name="model" id="model" data-level="3"><option value="2">Ultra</option></select>

        <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div id="litre-collection" class="select">-->

        <select class="litreSelect {prevLevelsIncluding: 'cat,year,make,model,litre'} litre" name="litre" id="litre"><option value="6">6</option></select>

        <!--</div>-->
                <div align="center">
            <input type="button" style=" padding:5px; margin:5px;" value="Clear" class="vafClear"><input type="button" style=" padding:5px; margin:5px;" class="vafSubmit" value="Submit">
        </div>
              </form>
```

which is working (when first select box is selected, then the next is loaded with relevant data by ajax) if all the `select` boxes are next to each other, but for design concern I need to add `<div>` around all select boxes and also let them work by ajax dropdown selection too.

Right now I am using `nextAll` function of jQuery, which is not a good option when structure changes. So anyone can guide me how to get it working with `div` around all select boxes ?

The script I am using currently is as below:

```
if(jQuery('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>_startSelect').size()) {
            var url = getUrl( jQuery(this).parent('form'), '<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>' );
            alert(jQuery('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>_startSelect').val());
            jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>_startSelect').html( loadingText );
            jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>_endSelect').html( loadingText );
            jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>_startSelect').load( url, {}, function(responseText) {
                jQuery(this).html(responseText);
                callbackFunc.apply( this );
            });  
            jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>_endSelect').load( url, {}, function(responseText) {
                jQuery(this).html(responseText);
                callbackFunc.apply( this );
            });
        } else {
            if(jQuery('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i ])?>Select').val() != "0")
            {
              var url = getUrl( jQuery(this).parent('form'), '<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>' );
              var NewVar = jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>Select').html( loadingText );
              jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>Select').html( loadingText );
              jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>Select').load( url, {}, function(responseText) {
                jQuery(this).html(responseText);
                callbackFunc.apply( this );
              });
            }
            else
            {
              //jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>Select').html('<option></option>').attr('disabled','disabled');
              //jQuery(this).nextAll('.<?=str_replace(' ','_',$levels[ $i + 1 ])?>Select').prop('disabled', true);
              jQuery(this).nextAll('select').each(function() {
                //jQuery(this).html('<option></option>').prop('disabled',true);
                jQuery(this).prop('disabled',true);
              });
            }
        }
```

I am not much of a scripting guy.

Comment: all that php in the js? do you really need to do it that way?

Comment: It is a prebuild module and that's the default code of module which I am using in many sites, but just for this site I need to add div around select boxes. All I am looking for is `nextAll` alternative for getting next-all select boxes even if they are enclosed by their respective div tags

Comment: Why your classes named this way - `yearSelect {prevLevelsIncluding: 'cat,year'} year` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**  `nextAll().children()`  It should work

**Explaination:**

Since The **nextAll() method** *returns all next sibling elements of the selected element.*

Now if you add **children() method** to it , than  children() method will *return all direct children of the selected elements.*

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7c4wxas1/)

Comment: I tried, but in my case(with above mentioned structure) it's not working. It throws error `TypeError: a is undefined` in jQuery 1.7 file